# Guide about use multiiple activity or not?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app for showing my favorite singers songs lyrics for about ten of his albums.
And this is predictable. First, I must create a menu, and then put some buttons. Each button navigates to album `Activity`.
Now I must implement one `Activity` for each album and after that, implement one activity for each song. And this is need about 100 Activity!!

What is better manner on your choice?
Note:I want to make a music player for each song I have, as well as a view for Showing lyrics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one generic Activity for displaying a song and make it dynamic enough so that you can populate it with your song data.

Reusing activities you've built is essential to creating an app of any kind.

Check this out for your list of albums / songs: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/listviewpart-1.html

When you click one of these you want to go to another Activity and pass it the data you need (like song name, duration and artist) and set your TextViews to the data passed through!

Comment: @Bashid I edited my post to include a helpful link.

Comment: Merci Beacoup. Now I know My Way. Good Luck

Comment: @Bashid Good luck. Thank you for being so polite!